# Loading div from subpage using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, load

I am using the following code:

```
$('#demo').load('url #newcontent');
```

The problem I am having is that if the URL and div id are separated by a space, nothing happens.

If there is no space, the second page gets loaded fully / redirected.

in both cases the console log only says:

> XHR finished loading: GET "url".

I have also tried like this:

```
<script>
    function loadDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "url" + "#newcontent", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

This loads the full page into #demo div

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Check the console for errors. The space is required between the URL and the selector of the element to retrieve - see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load) for more information

Comment: Are you sure you have both divs - ie a demo div on the page calling and a newcontent div on the loaded page.  Also just to make sure, url is an actual url you are using and not the above

Comment: It is an actual url, but without the file name and ending extension. Could that be the problem?

Demo div and newcontent div are set up correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you must do this with function here is example

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var img = new Image();
  $(img).one('load', function() {
  alert("image is loaded");
  });

 img.src = "source";


 $(img).appendTo('.imgContainer');
 });
```

Comment: this is a different use of load, OPs load is an ajax load, this is an onload

Comment: Ok, this actually loads the content from subpage, could you help me to set it up so it loads an ID of a DIV?

Comment: Sorry i dont think iam uderstand you what you want load? its a image or ID of div?

Comment: Sorry, content of a div which has it's own ID.